# How to change Swift property visibility in subclass

Tags: swift, swift2

Is there a way to change Swift property visibility in subclass without introducing new property?

What I would like to do is (having property initialized to default value is not mandatory requirement):

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    private var abc: Int = 0
}

public class MyClass: MyBaseClass
{
    public override var abc: Int = 0 // this cannot be compiled
}
```

Above code shows compiler error:

> Cannot override with stored property 'abc'

The only way I can currently solve this is introducing another property but that is not what I prefer to do:

```
public class MyClass: MyBaseClass
{
    public var abcd: Int
    {
        get
        {
            return abc
        }

        set
        {
            abc = newValue
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift has two types of properties: stored properties and computed properties. You can override both of them but the overriden version cannot be a stored property, you have to override using computed properties.

Note that a stored property is just a chunk of memory but a computed property is a set of two methods - a getter and a setter. You cannot override a chunk of memory with another chunk of memory but you can override a method.

See [Inheritance - Overriding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-ID193), section `Overriding Properties`

> You can override an inherited instance or type property to provide your own custom getter and setter for that property, or to add property observers to enable the overriding property to observe when the underlying property value changes.
>
> You can provide a custom getter (and setter, if appropriate) to override any inherited property, regardless of whether the inherited property is implemented as a stored or computed property at source. The stored or computed nature of an inherited property is not known by a subclass—it only knows that the inherited property has a certain name and type. You must always state both the name and the type of the property you are overriding, to enable the compiler to check that your override matches a superclass property with the same name and type.
>
> You can present an inherited read-only property as a read-write property by providing both a getter and a setter in your subclass property override. You cannot, however, present an inherited read-write property as a read-only property.

And a **Note:** under

> If you provide a setter as part of a property override, you must also provide a getter for that override. If you don’t want to modify the inherited property’s value within the overriding getter, you can simply pass through the inherited value by returning super.someProperty from the getter, where someProperty is the name of the property you are overriding.

which tells us exactly what to do:

```
public class MyClass: MyBaseClass {
    public override var abc: Int {
        get {
           return super.abc
        }
        set {
           super.abc = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the following would also work. We just have to make sure we have a computed property:

```
public class MyClass: MyBaseClass {
    public override var abc: Int {
        didSet {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks better

```
public class MyClass: MyBaseClass {
    override public var abc: Int {
        get {
            return super.abc
        }
        set {
            super.abc = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Some claims that this is a bug of the compiler, it doesn't synthesize correctly overridden properties.

Comment: Exactly the same solution I had. Considering that the error message for the original code is `error: cannot override with a stored property 'abc'`, it seems more like intended behavior than a bug to me.

Comment: Looks nice but I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS in playground for `let b = MyClass()
b.abc = 1`

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I have fixed that. The problem with overriding a variable is the fact that you cannot do that. Never. What you are actually overriding are methods, that is, the getter and the setter of the property.

Comment: Thanks, It works now. I am still getting used to Swift way of doing things. Can you please put this comment into answer too. It really explains what is going on in background.

Comment: @Sulthan can you explain why the documentation explicitly states you can override properties? Am I misunderstanding this scenario?https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html

Comment: @Jeff You can but you have to understand there are two types of properties - stored properties and computed properties. And you cannot override using a stored property. The documentation clearly states that you can override a property to provide a custom setter, getter or an observer (`willSet`, `didSet`)

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

```
    public class MyClass: MyBaseClass {
    private var abc: Int = 0
}


public class MyClass: MyBaseClass {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.abc = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to change visibility of property, not initialization.