# Swift is there an easy way to mark a superclass getter/setter as unavailable

Tags: ios, swift

So I have the following code:

```
public final class MyAdaptiveSprite: SKSpriteNode {

  private let textureColor: AdaptiveColor
  
  public init(texture: SKTexture, size: CGSize, color: AdaptiveColor) {
    textureColor = color
    super.init(texture: texture, color: .clear, size: size)
    adaptThemeChange()
  }

  @available(*, unavailable)
  public override var color: UIColor {
    // Still needs implementation, since `super.init` calls it. 
    // Can't use fatalError, or will crash
    get { return super.color }
    set { super.color = newValue }
  }

  public func adaptThemeChange() {
    // Have to call super, since we mark `color` as unavailable
    super.color = textureColor.lightModeOrDarkModeColor
  }
}
```

This code is a bit ugly, I simply want to hide `color` property, because I want my caller to only use `adaptThemeChange()` API, and not accidentally use `color` setter. However, I have to implement the whole setter/getter, which is tedious. Is there a more elegant way of marking an API as unavailable?

Another problem with this approach is that I can't use `self.color` **within** `MyAdaptiveSprite` anymore, because it's marked as unavailable including `MyAdaptiveSprite` itself. Is there a way to mark it unavailable to external callers, but not the class itself? (It's fine if it's not possible to do so).

Comment: Do you realise it is totally possible for someone to access `color` by first casting to the superclass `SKSpriteNode`?

Comment: `UIColor`s are supposed to adapt to theme changes automatically. You can create a dynamic color using [`init(dynamicProvider:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3238041-init) Does SpriteKit not support this? (I haven't tried)

Comment: Hiding it would violate the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: I don't know how you use it, may be you just need use SKSpriteNode as private property instead of subclassing it.

Comment: Inheritance might not be the best design. It also requires you to adhere to the Liskov substitution principle. Instead, use composition, i.e. a class (or struct) wrapping a SKSpriteNode instance having a specific API, possibly define the public API as a protocol.

Comment: no spritekit doesn't support dynamic provider (didn't work for me when i tried it)

Comment: I look at look at LSP - there's also "criticism" section, so i don't wanna treat it as a bible.

Comment: For the composition approach, there are just way too many APIs of SKSpriteNode that I want to expose (basically everything except for the `color`). That just can't scale

Comment: `SKSpriteNode`'s contract require a `color` property, you cannot inherit a class and violate it's contract. If you don't want a `color`, than you should not inherit `SKSpriteNode`, but I assume that's a no-go for your app.

Comment: BTW, there are tons of other properties in `SKSpriteNode` as well as it's parent `SKNode`, how come you want to hide only the `color` one?

Comment: Because it's very easy to misuse it by calling color, which breaks my "light/dark mode adaptability". Using all other properties won't be a misuse because I expect them to work the way it is.

Comment: But it's as easy to also misuse other properties that could break other things. The potential for bugs arises from any publicly writable member, which can be wrongly written to by other developers. Also, you mentioned that you want to be able to access the `color` property only from within the class, even if that would be possible, it would still not be a guarantee that it won't get a wrong value.

Comment: within the class is fine since i am the implemnetor and i know the details. i want to have an encapsulation so that the callers who dont know about the implementation details won't misuse it

Comment: Then the only way to do it is to expose another API than one over `SKSpriteNode`, basically composition over inheritance. But I doubt it will work for you.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `assertionFailure` to crash in debug builds if the property is used from outside the class, and use `super.color` inside the class, but this requires mode diligence from the writer of the class, and still doesn't prevent other to use `color`, just that it will crash at runtime if they do it.

Comment: i still prefer compiler checks to runtime crash

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to change Swift property visibility in subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786237/how-to-change-swift-property-visibility-in-subclass)?